# mingw in docker container no output

Tags: windows, docker, terminal, containers

I obviously do something wrong. Or threre is a bug. Anyway, on recent docker 17.03.1-ce, run various windows containers, e.g.:

```
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore
```

and see no output for mingw and cygwin tools:

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0E7C-C210

 Directory of C:\test

06/27/2017  08:43 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2017  08:43 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  20,098,813,952 bytes free

C:\test>bash

C:\test>bash -c 'mkdir aa'

C:\test>ls

C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0E7C-C210

 Directory of C:\test

06/27/2017  08:44 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2017  08:44 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2017  08:44 AM    <DIR>          aa
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  20,098,813,952 bytes free

C:\test>bash -c -v -x 'mkdir aa'

C:\test>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\test>bash -c -v -x 'mkdir aa' 2>a.txt

C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0E7C-C210

 Directory of C:\test

06/27/2017  08:51 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2017  08:51 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2017  08:51 AM                69 a.txt
06/27/2017  08:44 AM    <DIR>          aa
               1 File(s)             69 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  20,098,813,952 bytes free

C:\test>type a.txt
mkdir aa
+ mkdir aa
mkdir: cannot create directory 'aa': File exists
```

Docker log doesn't seem to have any errors nor warnings.

So far I also have tried:
- install git with chocolatey
- install git directly from zip froom github
- install msys2 with chocolatey and use bash from there
- install cygwin with chocolatey and use bash from there
- tried the same in different host and container terminals cmd.exe powershell.exe far.exe - issue remains the same

The same tools work properly on host machine, and they are working inside container, just output gets lost.

Any hint what I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/262), not sure why I wasn't able to find it before.

So, (kind of) workaround will be using container without -t flag